# Problems with mysql_upgrade

Tags: mysql

During restarting mysql I had come errors, one of them was

```
2013-05-16 12:48:06 56189 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
```

And I decided to try mysql_upgrade, but it failed:

```
Pavel-Kodentsevs-MacBook-Pro:bin pavelkodentsev$ ./mysql_upgrade -u root -p
Enter password: 
Looking for 'mysql' as: ./mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: ./mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
./mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

What can it be caused by? Pass is right, I've checked it several times.

Answer (score 1):

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

It cant connect to your local mysql server as root from localhost. Have you tried https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html

Try renaming .my.cnf if you have one

> mv /root/.my.cnf /root/.my.cnf.bak

and rerun the command.

Comment: But I do can connect to mysql server as root from localhost using mysql -u -p command

Comment: Nop, I don't have such file (.my.cnf)